# How does formatting a Python date object with str.format() work?

Tags: python, date, string-formatting

I've recently seen this string formatting example:

```
>>> from datetime import date
>>> 'Today is {0:%A}'.format(date.today())
'Today is Thursday'
```

I'm wondering how it works.

Comment: Have you asked that to Documentation or Google?

Comment: See https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=str.format#str.format and https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/string.html#string-formatting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `date` class defines the `__format__()` magic method, which is called by `str.format()` to produce a “formatted” string representation of an object. To quote the documentation for [`date.__format__()`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/datetime.html?highlight=strftime#datetime.date.__format__):

> Same as [`date.strftime()`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/datetime.html?highlight=strftime#datetime.date.strftime). This makes it possible to specify a format
>   string for a [`date`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/datetime.html?highlight=strftime#datetime.date) object in [formatted string literals](https://docs.python.org/3.7/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings) and when using
>   [`str.format()`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.format). For a complete list of formatting directives, see
>   [`strftime()` and `strptime()` Behavior](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/datetime.html?highlight=strftime#strftime-strptime-behavior).

Therefore, `'{:%A}'.format(date.today())` is equivalent to `date.today().strftime('%A')`.